# Add new line in column name of dynamic material table in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a material table with dynamic columns which currently look like -

[image]

But my expected output is like this -

[image]

What can i do to add new lines after PIN GROUNDED = 1 ? I tried adding BR but that didn't work .

My code for generating dynamic columns is -

```
      <mat-table matSort [dataSource]="gridDataSource">
      <ng-container [matColumnDef]="col" *ngFor="let col of columnsToDisplay">
      <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
                  {{col | uppercase}}
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                  {{element[col]}}
      </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <mat-header-row class="headerHeight" *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"
      [ngClass]="row.SEQ % 4 == 0 ? 'rows' : 'row'"></mat-row>
      </mat-table>
```

Comment: You can add BR and use the `raw` pipe in angular. Should print the html code and put the break in its place.

Answer (score 0):

In your `[dataSource]` you have to add an `\n` where you need a line break.
e.g.:

```
const datasource = { anyKey: "value with a \nline-break" }
```

And in your html add CSS styling on the HTML element `white-space: pre-line` e.g.:

```
<td mat-cell style="white-space: pre-line">{{element.value}}</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

With some research i got the solution .

We can use [innerHtml] property instead of {{colName}} . This makes the 
 tag in the string reflect as a horizontal break line .

```
<span [innerHTML]= "col | uppercase"></span>
```

Comment: This will block sorting of table.